# Change legend appearance when both "size" aesthetic and geom_smooth are required

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with continuous x and y variables, a third continuous variable mapped to "size" aesthetic, and a fourth discrete variable mapped to the "shape" aesthetic. The legend of the "size" scale shows bullets of different size if I only specify `geom_point()`, which is fine, but if I also specify `geom_smooth` the legend shows a line over the bullet, which is not what I want. Is there a way to keep only bullets in the legend when specifying `geom_smooth()`?

I tried to use

```
guides(size=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape="circle")))
```

but that did not work

Here is an MRE:

```
df <- tibble(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100), c=rnorm(100), d=rep(c("A", "B"), 50))
ggplot(df, aes(x=a, y=b, shape=d, size=c)) + 
  geom_point()
```

The code above produces the wanted legend for "size".

What I want is to add smoothing lines by group, with different linetypes:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=a, y=b, shape=d, size=c)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", aes(linetype=d), color="black")
```

The legend for size now has lines overlapping the bullets.

I'd like to have the legend as produced by the first code also when I add `geom_smooth()`.

Comment: Adding `show.legend = F` in your `geom_smooth` will keep it from being shown in any legends

Comment: Thanks, but I do want the legend for geom_smooth to be shown in order for the reader to understand the group the lines belong to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To separate the legends—in this case, linetype from size—you can give them different titles. That can be as minor a difference as adding a space to one, like `"d"` and `"d "`, although that's probably not the greatest idea.

I gave linetype its own title, so it gets its own separate legend. I also removed linetype from the `aes` of the size legend by giving it a linetype of `NA` (`NULL` should also work).

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(515)
df <- tibble::tibble(a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100), c=rnorm(100), d=rep(c("A", "B"), 50))
ggplot(df, aes(x=a, y=b, shape=d, size=c)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm", aes(linetype=d), color="black") +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(title = "d - line"),
         size = guide_legend(title = "c", override.aes = list(linetype = NA)))
```

[image]